# Why can;t I printf the 2-D array by array[][] format?

Tags: c, arrays, double-pointer

I am practicing my C program currently and I want to calculate two 2D matrix.

But I get confused when I use `printf()` to check these arrays. They break the program.

Code as below:

```
int matric_multi_main()
{
    int m1_row = 0;
    int m1_col = 0;
    int m2_row = 0;
    int m2_col = 0;
    int **matric1;
    int **matric2;

    printf("Please enter Matric 1 row: ");
    scanf("%d", &m1_row);
    printf("Please enter Matric 1 column: ");
    scanf("%d", &m1_col);
    printf("Please enter Matric 2 row: ");
    scanf("%d", &m2_row);
    printf("Please enter Matric 2 column: ");
    scanf("%d", &m2_col);

    if (m1_col != m2_row)
    {
        printf("Error matric size!!!\n");

        return 0;
    }

    /* Allovate memory for matric 1 */
    matric1 = malloc(m1_row * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < m1_row; i++)
    {
        matric1[i] = malloc(m1_col * sizeof(int));
    }

    /* Allovate memory for matric 2 */
    matric2 = malloc(m2_row * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < m2_row; i++)
    {
        matric2[i] = malloc(m2_col * sizeof(int));
    }

    /* Init matric 1 */
    for (int i = 0; i < m1_row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1_col; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d, %d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", matric1+i*m1_row+j);
        }
    }

    /* Init matric 2 */
    for (int i = 0; i < m2_row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2_col; j++)
        {
            printf("[%d, %d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", matric2+i*m2_row+j);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m1_row; i++)
    {
        printf("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < m1_col; j++)
        {
            //printf("%d ", *(matric1 + i*m1_row + j));  <- correctly
            //printf("%d ", &matric1[i][j]);  <-- display the data with wrong order
            printf("%d ", matric1[j][i]); <- break the program
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m2_row; i++)
    {
        printf("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < m2_col; j++)
        {
            //printf("%d ", *(matric2 + i*m2_row + j));
            printf("%d ", matric2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
}
```

I think I can use `matric1[i][j]` to get the correct data directly.

But the example on the website always use `array[][]` directly.

I can understand the different between my program and example.

Comment: @user3121023 Your comments seem to be to be 99% of an answer. Can I help you in any way to make one?

Comment: @user3121023Thanks for your answer so much. It seem that matric1[i][j] is not equal to *(*(matric1 + i) + j)). The result may be the non consecutive you memtion above?.

Comment: @user3121023 when I use scanf ( "%d", (*(matric1 + i) + j)); to assign data of this array, I can printf by printf("%d", *(*(matric1 + i) + j))); correctly (equal to printf("%d", [i][j]));, I am confuse about why I can use (*(matric1 + i*m1_row) + j)?